# What Is Faster One Port Per User, Or All Users On One port

Tags: java, sockets, networking

What would be faster for a realtime game server, one port per user on the server in which each user is passed a thread and receives a port assignment, or one port per user in which each thread is handed the socket after being established on the main thread?

Comment: This depends on so many factors. The only way to know is to try it in your environment.

Comment: How many players do you think will be served at a time?

Comment: All users in One port

Comment: @MikeW Factors such as what exactly?

Comment: @Close-voters It's only 'too broad' if you actually think it makes any difference, and that there really are numerous factors involved. It doesn't, and there aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a question of 'faster'. Once a connection is established it doesn't matter. The real issue is that your first alternative is not implementable without a lot of extra code which in itself will slow things down in the connect phase. A TCP server socket listens on a single fixed port which the clients know about, and they all connect to that port. If you then want to move them to another port you then have to open it, tell them what port it is, and accept another connection. It's all pointless.